# Removing formatting symbols from sql server management studio query editor

Tags: sql-server-2008

I had accidentally switched on the formatting symbols to show (don't exactly remember the key sequence). Now my query looks like below.

[image]

I would like to disable it but I could not find anything like that. It is creating a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting is called "View White Space" and is located under the Edit -> Advanced submenu:

[image]

Comment: This really helped my troubles go away. tysm